# Creating React.js using npx create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs

C:\Users\Price Charles>npx create-react-app larotiks

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Price Charles\larotiks.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

I'm creating my react project but it always stuck here and can't continue creating my project. please help me

Comment: Are there any errors that are happening? Are you stopping the process early? Have your tired just letting it sit for a while?

Comment: no, there is no error, but I waited about 4hrs from now.

Comment: Is there any kind of `npx --verbose`?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Dann Johnrem De Guzman,

There are multiple scenarios your npx create-react-app larotiks stuck

Here is the multiple solutions to issue Please try one by one:

1. Update your Node Packages to latest version

   npm install npm@latest -g
2. Remove the temp files in your system  (windows)

   Ctrl + R -> %TEMP% -> delete All temp files
3. Check your network if worked or not
4. Run npx create-react-app larotiks Command with administrator permission
5. Instead of Run npx create-react-app larotiks you first run "npm install create-react-app -g" then run create-react-app larotiks
6. Finally nothing is helps to you then uninstall your node and install the latest version from the following url (Windows)

https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.4.0/node-v14.4.0-x64.msi

I hope it's help you to resolve this issue thank you.